# long to wide with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

I have a data frame which is structured like this one:

```
dd <- data.frame(round = c("round1", "round2", "round1", "round2"),
                 var1 = c(22, 11, 22, 11),
                 var2 = c(33, 44, 33, 44),
                 nam = c("foo", "foo", "bar", "bar"),
                 val = runif(4))

   round var1 var2 nam        val
1 round1   22   33 foo 0.32995729
2 round2   11   44 foo 0.89215038
3 round1   22   33 bar 0.09213526
4 round2   11   44 bar 0.82644723
```

From this I would like to obtain a data frame with two lines, one for each value of `nam`, and variables 
`var1_round1`, `var1_round2`, `var2_round1`, `var2_round2`, `val_round1`, `val_round2`. I would *really* like to find a dplyr solution to this.

```
  nam var1_round1 var1_round2 var2_round1 var2_round2 val_round1 val_round2
1 foo          22          11          33          44 0.32995729  0.8921504
2 bar          22          11          33          44 0.09213526  0.8264472
```

The closest thing I can think of would be to use `spread()` in some creative way but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `tidyr/dplyr` to do this.  We `gather` the dataset to 'long' format, `unite` the 'variable' and 'round' to create 'var' and then `spread` to 'wide' format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(dd, variable, value, var1, var2, val) %>%
         unite(var, variable, round) %>% 
         spread(var, value)
#  nam val_round1 val_round2 var1_round1 var1_round2 var2_round1 var2_round2
#1 bar  0.7187271  0.6022287          22          11          33          44
#2 foo  0.2672339  0.7199101          22          11          33          44
```

NOTE: The 'val' are different as the OP didn't set a `seed` for `runif`